# Simple_fields_for with cocoon not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cocoon-gem

I have a one-to-many association in Ruby on Rails:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rides
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rides, allow_destroy: true
end

### and ###

class Ride < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bookings
end
```

The booking and ride views and controllers were scaffolded.

I wanted an "Add rides" button in my bookings form:

```
= simple_form_for(@booking) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?

  .form-inputs
    .container
      .row
        .col-6
          = f.input :first_name
          = f.input :phone_number
        .col-6
          = f.input :last_name
          = f.input :email
        .col-12
          = f.input :company


### here is the simple fields that does not work:

  = f.simple_fields_for :rides do |ride|
    = render 'rides/form', :f => ride
    = link_to_add_association 'add ride', f, :rides
```

However, nothing gets displayed and I don't know why.

**Things I've tried:**

1. Add `rides_build`
   I tried to add this to the booking controller

```
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @booking.build_rides
  end
```

But it only gave me an error "undefined method `build_rides' for #Booking:0x000000010575c578"

2. Add `rides.build`

```
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @booking.rides.build
  end
```

This also gave me an error message: "undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass"

3. Add only `ride`

```
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @booking.build
  end
```

This just didn't do anything. No error, but the problem wasn't solved.

4. Change `ApplicationRecord` to `ActiveRecord::Base`
   This solved it for someone else, but not for me.

Might also want to add that absolutely nothing gets rendered that's inside the simple_fields_for, not even a simple `h1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is the correct way and should work, but you have an error in your `Ride` model, it should say

```
 belongs_to :booking
```

Note: the `simple_fields_for` iterates over nested children, as long as there are none, nothing will get rendered.